UiPath Studio autopilot generates classic Activities
I'm testing UiPath Studio's Autopilot functionality and typed "Read Range from a excel file and write to a csv file".  It seem generates a sequence using classic activities. 
But I want to use modern activities because classic ones are depreciated or not recommended.  How can I let the autopilot generate sequence using modern activities by default?  I'm using UiPath Studio version 2025.0.157


To make Autopilot use modern activities by default in UiPath Studio (2025.0.157), here’s what you can do:

Check Your Project Settings:
•   Go to Project Settings → General Tab.
•   Ensure the Modern Design Experience is enabled.
•   In the newer versions, this option is usually enabled by default, and you might not see the toggle.

Update Your Activity Packages:
Make sure you’re using the latest versions of:
•   UiPath.Excel.Activities
•   UiPath.System.Activities
You can update them through Manage Packages → Official Feed.

Be Clear with Autopilot Prompts:
Autopilot relies heavily on your instructions. Instead of typing:
•   “Read Range from an Excel file and write to a CSV file.”
Try:
•   “Read Range from an Excel file using modern activities and write to a CSV file using modern activities.”


This small clarification helps Autopilot understand your preference.

Replace Classic Activities Manually (if needed):
If Autopilot still generates classic activities:
•   Swap Read Range (classic) with Excel Read Range (modern).
•   Replace Write CSV (classic) with Write CSV (modern).

Restart Studio:
Sometimes, restarting UiPath Studio can ensure all configurations and updates take effect properly.


Following these steps should guide Autopilot to use modern activities by default.
